# GTK: Warning cannot display

Tags: 14.04, apt, upgrade, dpkg, gtk

I just upgraded from 13.10 to 14.04 and I am experiencing problems with my dependencies as follows

`sudo apt-get install` gives

> You might want to run `apt-get -f install` to correct these. The
>   following packages have **unmet dependencies**: `libmatroska6`
>   **Depends**: libebml4 but it is not installed. **Recommends** : `libdvdcss2` but it is not installed.

on trying `apt-get -f install` gives

> gtk warning cannot open display at `/usr/share/per15/Debconf/FrontEnd/Gnome.pm` line 94, <> line 1 .

I tried  `dpkg-reconfigure -f` results an `dpkg:error:need an action option`

other unmet dependency package is `vlc-nox`

Comment: did the whole procedure got this problem on `sudo apt-get -u dist-upgrade`

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/universe/libe/libebml/libebml4_1.3.0-2_amd64.deb 
sudo dpkg -i --force-overwrite /home/paperfairy/Downloads/libebml4_1.3.0-2_amd64.deb 
sudo apt-get purge libebml3
```

Comment: errors where encountered while processing `libebml4_1.3.0-2_amd64.deb` **trying to overwrite** `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libebml.so.4`

Comment: purge again listed the unmet dependencies of `vlc-nox` and `libmatroska6`